# Why am I getting a broken pipe error when adding data to the database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Not sure if there's a better way to do this but I have a sign up page on my site and after a user signs up I add their initial data(stuff in the `__init__` data model) then I start adding some other info in the same section which is giving me a `broken pipe` error. Oddly the code seems to work since the entries I'm expecting are in the database. I have tried moving around the `.flush()` command to see if it helps but it doesn't seem to be.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Dropbox/code/eclipseWorkSpace/website/pyramidwiki/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 134, in handle_write
    flush()
  File "/Users/me/Dropbox/code/eclipseWorkSpace/website/pyramidwiki/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 249, in _flush_some
    num_sent = self.send(chunk)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 365, in send
    result = self.socket.send(data)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Here's my code:

```
if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
    firstname = request.params['firstname']
    lastname = request.params['lastname']
    email = request.params['email']
    password = request.params['password']
    try:
        new_user = Users(email, firstname, lastname, password)
        DBSession.add(new_user)
        #DBSession.flush() #commit so we get error if any
        #add some other info
        user_data = DBSession.query(Users).filter(Users.email==email).first()
        user_data.join_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        #create random number for verification url
        user_data.vertified = id_generator(50)

        DBSession.flush() #doesn't seem to make a difference where the flush is
        return HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('new'))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: broken pipes are generally associated with a request timeout or the client closing the connection.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out where/why its happening? This started after I added the `user_data` variable and started adding data after the initial adding of the user.  Or is there a better way to achieve it?  There's some information I want to add after the user has been created.

Comment: I'm having that same issue but can't figure out what is causing this. Did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not answer you question directly, but "you're doing it all wrong"(tm) :)

You don't need to re-query User object after you added it to the session - what's more, trying to query it from the database without doing session.flush() first will result in an error because there's no record in the database yet. I'd do something like this:

```
if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
    firstname = request.params['firstname']
    lastname = request.params['lastname']
    email = request.params['email']
    password = request.params['password']
    try:
        new_user = Users(email, firstname, lastname, password)
        new_user.join_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        new_user.verified = id_generator(50)

        DBSession.add(new_user)
        DBSession.flush() # should fail if user email is in the database
        return HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('new'))
```

Also, you need to check that all branches of execution (i.e. the except: clause, the else: clause of "if 'form.submitted' in request.params" return something meaningful - you may be getting the exception because your view function returns None in some conditions. Actually, that's probably what was happening - the "user_data = DBSession.query(Users)" line was raising an exception, and the except: part was not returning anything

Answer (score 2):

I too struggled with the same problem on my Pyramid project and contrary to comments on github, it wasn't with `waitress`.

In my case, the problem of `Error: Broken Pipe` only occured whenever I used redirects (`HTTPFound`, `HTTPMovedPermanently` etc.). Since your function also uses `HTTPFound`, I think the problem is the same.

Atleast for me, this error was due to `pyramid_debugtoolbar` extension. The reason is probably that whenever our view does soemthing like

`return HTTPFound(foo)`

it sends out a 302 in the header and a `Connection:Close`. The `pyramid_debugtoolbar` extension adds a lengthy body to the response. The client on seeing the header, closes the connection and does not accept the lengthy debug body. Hence the `Broken Pipe` message (Atleast that is what Wireshark shows).

Try disabling the `pyramid_debugtoolbar` in your app's `.ini`, it might help.